# The closed interval $[0,1]$ is sequentially compact

Tags: general-topology

I try to show that the closed interval $[0,1]$ is sequentially compact. Can anyone check my attempt? Thanks!

Let $(x_n)_n$ be sequence in [0,1] and suppose it has no convergent subsequence. Then there exists a number $C\in (0,1)$ such that $C<\big|x_n-x_m\big
|$ for all distinct $n,m$. Say $C=1/k$ for some integer $k>0$. Then we may consider $k$ disjoint intervals 
$$\Big[0,\frac{1}{k}\Big),\Big[\frac{1}{k},\frac{2}{k}\Big), ..., \Big[\frac{k-1}{k},1\Big]$$ Since their union gives the closed interval $[0,1]$ and by the Pigeonhole principle, at least one them contains at least two terms $x_k,x_l$ of the sequence $(x_n)_n$. So we get $\big|x_n-x_m\big
|<C$, contradiction.

Comment: It seems to me that you did not deny correctly the existence of a converging subsequence.

Comment: You can see that something's wrong here because the same argument holds for $[0,1)$, which is not compact. The problem is that we need not have $|x_m-x_n|$ bounded below - take, for example, $x_n=1-1/n$.

Comment: How do you get from "no convergent subsequence" to the existence of a $C$ with the property you specify? Somewhere your argument needs to contain a step that works for $[0,1]$ but doesn't work for $(0,1)$, and it's not clear where it is here -- that means _at least_ that you're leaving too many details implicit.

Comment: Your argument actually shows that every sequence in $[0,1]$ has a **Cauchy** subsequence. This is why the same argument works equally well in $(0,1)$. To complete the argument you need to show that every Cauchy sequence in $[0,1]$ is convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assuming that $x_n$ has no convergent subsequences, you are assuming that $x_n$ has no *Cauchy* subsequences. However, in an incomplete metric space, Cauchy is not the same as convergent. For example, in the sequentially non-compact space $(0,1)$, the sequence $1/n$ is Cauchy, but has no convergent subsequences. Your argument misses this possibility.

One idea to fix your argument is to argue that if $x_n$ has no subsequences that converge in the interior of $[0,1]$, then it will have at least one subsequence that converges to either $0$ or $1$.